# Deserialize missing values of type to certain value

Tags: f#, json.net

I have made a wrapper type called `Skippable<'a>` (an F# discriminated union, not unlike `Option`) specifically meant for indicating which members should be excluded when serializing types:

```
type Skippable<'a> =
  | Skip
  | Serialize of 'a
```

I have functioning converters, but during deserialization, I want missing JSON values to be serialized to the `Skip` case of the DU (instead of `null` as is currently happening).

I know of `DefaultValueAttribute`, but that only works with constant values, and besides I don't want to use an attribute on each and every `Skippable`-wrapped property in my DTOs.

Is it possible in some way to tell Newtonsoft.Json to populate missing values of a certain type (`Skippable<'a>`) with a certain value of that type (`Skip`)? Using converters, contract resolvers, or other methods?

Comment: Write a custom converter for `Skippable<_>`?

Comment: Agreed, converters work good in this case. You can take inspiration from haf's OptionConverter: https://github.com/haf/Newtonsoft.Json.FSharp/blob/master/src/JsonNet/Converters/OptionConverter.fs

Comment: A converter seems to be no help here, because it doesn't seem to be called for properties that are entirely missing from the input JSON. I found a potential fix, though (added answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making `Skippable` a struct union is one way to do it, since then the default value (e.g. using `Unchecked.defaultOf`) seems to be the first case with any fields (none, in this case) at their default values.

```
[<Struct>]
type Skippable<'a> =
  | Skip
  | Serialize of 'a

// Unchecked.defaultof<Skippable<obj>> = Skip
```

This is part of the [FSharp.JsonSkippable](https://github.com/cmeeren/FSharp.JsonSkippable) library, which allows you to control in a simple and strongly typed manner whether to include a given property when serializing (and determine whether a property was included when deserializing), and moreover, to control/determine exclusion separately of nullability.